# A custom decorator to be called before every view using middleware

Tags: python, django

I have a custom decorator in a file and I need that every API call this decorator. I don't want to write `@decorator_name` before every view. I think this can be done using middleware but I am not sure how to do it.

I have tried middleware like this

```py
class DefaultAccountMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):

        return update_latest_account(view_func)(self, request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
```

This is the decorator:

```py
def update_latest_account(f):
@wraps(f)
    def decorator(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        user_id = request.user.id
        print('hi')
        user = User.objects.filter(id = user_id).first()
        if user is not None:
            account_id = request.META.get("HTTP_ACCOUNT_ID", None)
            user.latest_account_id = account_id
            user.save()
        return f(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

Comment: What happens when you use this code? Although one obvious issue is that you shouldn't be passing `self`.

Comment: It gives me error 'DefaultAccountMiddleware' object has no attribute 'encoding'

Comment: Yes, as I say, that's because you're passing `self`.

Comment: but if I do not pass self then it gives another error 'decorator() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)'

Comment: just look at the doc of django decorators, write an empty decorator doing nothing, make sure it works and only then copy paste the relevant code from you (without changing the signature of any function)

Comment: my decorator works fine I have tested it. But how can I do by middleware?